# Screenupdating not flipping

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

In Excel 2010 the method described below, the ScreenUpdating works correctly.  But in 2007, it doesnt flip and the worksheet operations are visually being seen.

#### VBA Usage:

```
Dim scrup As Boolean: scrup = DisableScreenUpdating(Application.ScreenUpdating)
```

#### Method Declaration:

```
Function DisableScreenUpdating(val As Boolean) As Boolean
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
   ' Disable ScreenUpdating, for seemless operation
   If val Then
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   End If
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

   DisableScreenUpdating = val
End Function
```

#### Question:

What am i missing in 2007 that 2010 is either assuming or is working correctly?

- Still tracking down the bug cause it is still happening on 1 version of the file but other two versions it will not.  The Versions all have the same code-base but based on various settings change representation to the end-user(s).

#### NOTE:

- Please DO NOT focus on the "Why i am doing this", and more of what situations would cause the ScreenUpdating method to NOT be changed from `True` to `False`.

Comment: wouldn't you need to add `val = False` under `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the Function. Otherwise, DisableScreenUpdating will always equal the original parameter passed into it.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman That is not the problem, as stated this logic works correctly in 2010, but in 2007 it does not accept the value change.

Comment: I see nothing here that would cause it not to work in 2007. I'm going to offer an alternative below in an answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: Yeah thats what i am getting.  Im sure its a Application Setting or Workbook setting but cant think of any setting that would block the ability to assign a value to `ScreenUpdating`.

Comment: Might be a silly question but I have to ask: why? Why would you want to overload the `ScreenUpdating` property in the first place? Is it not clear and concise enough already?

Comment: overload?  Im not overloading the method.  Its called turning off the ScreenUpdating, to speed up the file, due to row/column hiding and Dynamic calculations being updated.  After the processes are done it is turned back on.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem in Excel 2010 Professional Plus. In one of my forms, when I assign Application.ScreenUpdating = false, it goes false. In the other form, it doesn't. I check the value right after it is assigned false, and it is still true.  I tried exporting/importing all my code to see if it was a memory leak problem. I hope someone can figure this out.

Comment: @ShariW you need to figure out the points where you need to turn off ScreenUpdating.  At those points, check for current value, if its not set, then store the previous value in the function, and then turn it off.  Basically use Dave Lewis suggestion below, but i did an opener and closer.  At the top of your Method, Check if its not already disabled, if not then save current state, then turn off in the conditional block.  At the end of the method check the saved state and flip back screen updating if it was previously enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try eliminating the conditional and see if the problems is still there.  That ways you'd know if it has something to do with conditional or not or 'val'.

```
Function DisableScreenUpdating() As Boolean
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  DisableScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Assuming this makes your bug go away, I'd then focus on the call....

```
DisableScreenUpdating(Application.ScreenUpdating)
```

Perhaps the bug something to do with reading the ScreenUpdating property, followed shortly by write. That's just a guess though.

Also, I'd search your project for any other usage of Application.ScreenUpdating.  There may be some other code causing the updating to return to True.

Comment: I stepped through the method, and it hits the `False` assignment but after evaluating `ScreenUpdating` through the immediate window, it still evaluates to `True` at the end of method.

Comment: Maybe try... Function DisableScreenUpdating(ByVal val As Boolean) As Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, is there a function to enable ScreenUpdating?  Your code only disables it.  Here is your code modified with code that I use:

```
Dim scrup As Boolean: scrup = DisableScreenUpdating(Not Application.ScreenUpdating)

'Disable ScreenUpdating, for seemless operation
Function DisableScreenUpdating(val As Boolean) As Boolean
  With Application
    If .ScreenUpdating = val Then  'Gets rid of flashes for changing it to the same
      .ScreenUpdating = Not val
    End If

    'Doesn't matter what happens above, this is based on what Excel would send back
    DisableScreenUpdating = Not .ScreenUpdating
  End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the bug...yet the statement works, only the VBA-editor doesnt see changes.
However you can see the change by assigning a variable and then read it in the VBA-editor.

```
    >Sub testing()
    >Dim i As Long
    >
    >Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    >i = Application.ScreenUpdating
    >MsgBox "Assigned to i...real value = " & CBool(i)
    >
    >Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    >i = Application.ScreenUpdating
    >MsgBox "Value of Application.ScreenUpdating = " & CBool(i)
    >End Sub
```